# error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

Tags: regex, go

When I try this regex in golang I'm getting regex parsing error.

> error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

```
regexp.MustCompile("^(?!On.*On\\s.+?wrote:)(On\\s(.+?)wrote:)$"),
```

Can someone tell me why its not working and help me to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The go regexp package uses RE2 syntax, not PCRE https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

Comment: `(?!re)  before text not matching re (NOT SUPPORTED)` from the page [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Comment: @svasa Any alternate ways to make it work?

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the link. Any alternate way?

Comment: Use `regexp.MustCompile("^On\\s(.+?)wrote:$")` and `regexp.MustCompile("^On.*On\\s.+?wrote:")` and check if the first one is true and the second is false.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks..

Comment: I have this same issue, and am trying to reproduce it. It would help if I knew what this is supposed to match, so that I can apply the solution to my use case.

Comment: @MikeWarren Go regex does not support lookarounds, thus, in each case, workarounds may be unique.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go regex does not support lookarounds.

As a workaround, you may use

```
regexp.MustCompile(`^On\s(.+?)wrote:$`)
```

and

```
regexp.MustCompile(`^On.*On\s.+?wrote:`)
```

and check if the first one matches the string  and the second does not.

You could also add an optional capturing group `(.*On)?`

```
regexp.MustCompile(`^On(.*On)?\s.+?wrote:`)
```

and check if there is a match and return *true* if the Group 1 ends with `On` - if yes, return *false*, else *true*.